# Remove a folder without confirm deletion of every single file in nnn file manager

Tags: terminal, file-management, console

Recently I started to use the file manager nnn. It seems to be fun, except for deleting folders.

Is it somehow possible to delete a folder with this file manager, without confirming to delete every single file in it?

I've found the following issue: https://github.com/jarun/nnn/issues/683

What would be a simple work around for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you linked to answers this question:

```
`space` to select files/directories
`x` to start the delete process
`s` to apply it for selected
`y` to confirm (rm -rf 1 file(s) [Esc cancels])
```

For the final step if you press `enter` you get the recursive prompts.

Comment: I just accidentially deleted too many files with this command sequence. I selected some files in a folder, but without me noticing, I had previously hit the 'a' key in the parent folder, while doing a pattern search, and hence everything were deleted. Be aware.

Comment: Right. Be careful with this command.